# OpenCV Projectpoints makes wrong Z axis (calibrated with chessboard)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I want to calibrate my cameras and plot a xyz axis. ( like shown on this link: http: //docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html )

Unfortunately, my calibration is doing something weird and I can't seem to fix it. I made an cad-model to minimize other possible errors...

So basically, i do two steps :

1. calibrate each camera
2. use projectpoints to plot the lines

I don't know where it goes wrong...

Variables from cameraCalibration. The points from imagepoints are found by a chessboard.

```
vector< vector<cv::Point2f> > imagePoints;
vector< vector< cv::Point3f> > objectPoints;

vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
cv::Mat intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs;
```

The code to find the points

```
cv::Point2f clsCameraControl::FindSpecific(cv::Point3f o3Dpoint)
{
    cv::Mat  rvec, tvec;
    rvec.create(1, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    tvec.create(1, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    rvec = rvecs[0].clone(); 
    tvec = tvecs[0].clone();

    cv::solvePnP(objectPoints[0], imagePoints[0], intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs, rvec, tvec);

    vector<cv::Point3f> Input1;
    vector <cv::Point2f> Output1;
    Input1.insert(Input1.end(), o3Dpoint);
    Output1.clear();
    cv::projectPoints(Input1, rvec, tvec, intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs, Output1);

    return Output1[0];
 }
```

[This image represents the four results i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju9o1.png) (plotting the X (green), Y (red) and Z (blue) axis)

The Z axis is always wrong. It should just be up (or at least all wrong in the same direction)

The base pictures i used are [in this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ8EG.jpg), if you want to try it yourself (i made them myself so free use for everyone!)

Does somebody know why and how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem: take more pictures...

Comment: Do you mean during the chessboard calibration? How many pictures did you use?

Comment: Instead of using one picture for the calibration for each camera, I used around 60 pictures per camera. Each picture had the chessboard in another position, this way the calibration algorithm in open cv could calculate the intrinsic, distortion parameters and the rotation and translation vector more accurately.

Comment: @fivezero05 in my case the Z axis is always translated with a good starting point (like in your case), but the other end lands in (-10,-2) or something like that, resulting a with a diagonal blue line throughout the whole picture. Do you think this could be the calibration? How did you implement calibrating with multiple boards? Do you just iterate over the same matrix variables?